# Error Message in the android Logcat

Tags: android, message, android-logcat, dex

Whenever i load my app i get this weird Logcat message, which doesnt result into a crash but still worries me.

I have looked into different forums and found out that Dex is the code on which java runs. I still dont know why I get this message.

Does someone know what this error message is all about and how I can fix it?

> 07-11 13:53:53.277 19014-19075/com.example.abba.everythingright
>   E/zygote64: Dex checksum does not match for dex:
>   /data/data/com.example.abba.everythingright/files/instant-run/dex-temp/reload0x0000.dex.Expected:
>   1564265601, actual: 2911718928

Comment: Read this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1228721/The-Dex-File-Format

Comment: This caused by development tool called Instant Run. You won't see that in your release builds. If this error keeps bothering, you can disable Instant Run in Android Studio's settings.

Comment: @AlexLipov Good answer. You should post it as such :)

Comment: @JesusFreke Done :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This caused by development tool called Instant Run.
You won't see that in your release builds.
If this error keeps bothering, you can disable Instant Run in Android Studio's settings.

Comment: I have turned off the Instant Run and I still experiencing this issue. What else could be a reason?

Comment: @Ωmega Your error probably slightly different. Note that OP's error contains 
**instant-run** in path (/data/data/com.example.abba.everythingright/files/instant-run/dex-temp/reload0x0000.dex). If you're not using instant-run, files in instant-run folder won't be created.