# Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted

Tags: android, logcat

App is running without problems, but in Logcat I see this error:

```
Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
zygote64: Dex checksum does not match for dex: /data/data/com.mantas.vaistai/files/instant-run/dex-temp/reload0x0000.dex.Expected: 1592914573, actual: 1910341331
```

What does Zygote mean?
Is it something serious?
Do I have to pay attention to it?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: it's caused by Instant Run an shouldn't happen in release build.

Zygote is the init-process for Android, it simplifies runtime loading for applications by preloading their parts at boot and sharing with apps that are started later.

`Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted`
is not actualy an error, just log notification that current process is whitelisted for permissions checks.

Information about checksum error message you receive is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51298020

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project. That worked for me. I had added few dependencies and then removed them. Maybe that caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the version of the implementation.

For example, from:

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.1.0'
```